# Forcing HTTPS with .htaccess on site with Wordpress in subfolder

Tags: apache-http-server, https, wordpress, htaccess

I can't get my .htaccess file to work to force HTTPS traffic

Site structure that I see if I ftp to my hosting provider:

```
/
  domains
    mydomainname.com
      public_html
        blog
```

- The files for my site start in `public_html` (`index.html` etc)
- I have a WordPress installation in `blog`
- Wordpress settings have been set to https: (General settings mention `https://www.mydomainname.com/blog` as the Wordpress URL).
- SSL certificate is working fine if I go to the domain
- Initially there was only a `.htaccess` in `blog`, containing:

> # BEGIN WordPress
>       
>       RewriteEngine On
>       RewriteBase /blog/
>       RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
>       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>       RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
>       
>       # END WordPress

All kinds of tutorials I see mention that I should add this to the start of `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomainname.com/$1 [R,L]
```

.. and that I should place this file 'in the root of my site'.

If I have no (other) `.htaccess` file:

- I can browse go to `https://www.mydomainname.com`, follow links into the WP blog and browse around there, all https:
- If I go to `http://www.mydomainname.com`, follow links into the WP blog, these will turn into https:

If I place a modified htaccess in several locations I get issues like (depending on what `.htaccess` contents/locations I'm trying):

- If I go to `www.mydomainname.com` it redirects to `https://www.mydomainname.com` and I get "Server not found"; or:
- No forcing from http: to https:

Questions:

- Should the `.htaccess` be placed in `mydomainname.com` or `public_html` (i.e. which folder is that famous 'root of my site')? I have tried both.
- Must it *also* be placed in `blog`? If so, do they need to be identical?
- What are the proper contents of the `.htaccess` file(s)?

I have tried all kinds of variations, but can't get it to work - obviously not the right variation yet.

FWIW: I assume my hosting provider uses Apache. I have no control over its configuration.

Comment: Do you keep in mind that some browsers cache the webpage, and as such the .htaccess may not redirect properly? Chrome is particularly crazy about this. Shift-F5 should do a force reload, but sometimes even that doesn't work and you really have to clear the cache through the chrome menu. I've been stumbed getting the exact same to work and when I tried it in a different browser and it all worked, it finally hit me that it was the cache that played tricks on me.

Comment: Another unfortunate possibility is that your provider might not allow `.htaccess`, or might not allow all possible features. This is especially true with shared hosting, where multiple customer's websites are hosted on the same server.

Comment: @LPChip I restart the browser (and I wait)

Comment: @jpaugh My provider allows htaccess. One of their support pages mentions those three lines and the phrase 'in the main folder of your website'

Comment: @JanDoggen Restarting the browser is not enough to clear the cache. Shift+F5 should do so; you might also try using another browser, which you usually don't use; or, you could try clearing the cache. [Here's an app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn) that does so conveniently. Disclaimer: never used it.

Comment: @jpaugh I tried all of these; including Ctrl-F5. My tests have also extended across several days, new certs, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue you should put your new .htaccess file in public_html folder.

Try the [following](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS) with mod_rewrite in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.example.com/foo/ to https://www.example.com/foo/
# The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf or .htaccess context
```

These three lines *also* have to be added to the .htaccess file in the `blog` folder, modifying the `RewriteRule` to reflect that subfolder:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/blog/$1 [R,L]
```

It might be also useful to apply mod_ssl to force SSL with the [SSLRequireSSL](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequiressl) Directive:

> This directive forbids access unless HTTP over SSL (i.e. HTTPS) is
>   enabled for the current connection. This is very handy inside the
>   SSL-enabled virtual host or directories for defending against
>   configuration errors that expose stuff that should be protected. When
>   this directive is present all requests are denied which are not using
>   SSL.
>   Keep in mind that this will not do a redirect to https by itself.

Comment: This is basically it. I have added what *also* needs to be done to the .htaccess file in the blog subfolder

Comment: Can you past your htaccess file from your blog directory please?

Answer (score 0):

This is a summary of the article
[Force HTTPS On All Pages Of Your WordPress Site](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/12/force-https-pages-wordpress-site/)
describing how to make an entire WordPress blog secure via HTTPS.

1. **Force SSL for administrator and sign in pages**
   Add the following line to the `wp-config.php` file at the root of your WordPress directory:
   `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);`
2. **Set https in Settings**
   In your WordPress administrator dashboard, go to `Settings -> General` and change both URLs to have `https://` rather than `http://`:
   [image]
3. **Update .htaccess**
   Add rewrite rules in the `.htaccess` file found at the root of the WordPress application:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
       RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
       RewriteBase /
       RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```

Two lines were added saying that if the current port isn’t 443, then rewrite the URL to use HTTPS with a 301 redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

4. **Empty all caches for your application**